# convert django variable to int in a template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

I am trying to make a paginator (using twitter bootstrap) for the list of users on my site. The html code I took from twitter bootstrap looks like this:

```
    <div class="pagination" >
    <ul>
    {% if users.has_previous %}
    <li><a href="?page={{ users.previous_page_number }}">Prev</a></li>
    {% endif %}

    <li><a href="/users/?page=1">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="/users/?page=2">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="/users/?page={{users.number}}">{{users.number}}</a></li>
    <li><a href="/users/?page=4">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="/users/?page=5">...</a></li>

    {% if users.has_next %}
    <li><a href="?page={{ users.next_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
    </div>
```

I don't know what to write in dots' place yet.
How can I convert variable {{users.number}} to int to make operations with numbers and get ( {{users.number}}-1 ) and etc. to put them instead of dots?

I tried to it with filters but it doesn't work. I guess I can use them only in {% %} and not in {{}}.

Is it possible to make it right in the template? Or should I make adding in views.py and then pass to my template?

Comment: May be you shouldn't reinvent the wheel. Have you looked at [django-bootstrap-pagination](https://github.com/jmcclell/django-bootstrap-pagination) or [django-bootstrap-toolkit](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap-toolkit)?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you.But I need to gain an understanding in django's variables anyway. Do you know what to do with the problem described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `add` filter tries to autoconvert arguments into integers.  So `{{ value|add:2 }}` or `{{ value|add:"2" }}`  would return 6 if value can be converted into an int. And `{{ value|add:-2 }}` should return 4.

But I think a templatetag or filter would be also suitable for this. 
Just a simple function which gets the desired number, and maybe the steps in both directions, e.g. 2, and then return a list of `[n-2, n-1, n, n+1, n+2]`. Then you can loop through the list adding the li-tags.

This would be an example of the  filter:

```
# templates/templatetags/calculate_numbers.py

from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def calculate_numbers(n, steps):
    n = int(n)     
    return range(n-steps, n+steps+1)
```

And on your template:

```
{% load calculate_numbers %}

{% for n in users.number|calculate_numbers:2 %}
<li><a href="/users/?page={{ n }}">{{ n }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```